# Configuration changes in kafka appender for log4j2.xml?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, log4j2, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-config

I am using log4j2 kafka appender and log4j2.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="info" name="spring-boot-log-to-kafka-example" packages="com.ms.lib.infrastructure.eurekaservice">
    <Appenders>
        <Kafka name="kafkaAppender" topic="0v8uyhvb-logs">
            <JSONLayout />
            <Property name="bootstrap.servers">xyz.com:9094,xyz.com:9094,xyz.com:9094</Property>
            <Property name="security.protocol">SASL_SSL</Property>
            <Property name="sasl.mechanism">SCRAM-SHA-256</Property>
            <Property name="sasl.jaas.config">org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="uname" password="pwd-gkB8qv4P";
            </Property>
        </Kafka>

        <!--stdout/stderr included for testing Oozie log4j edits-->
        <Console name="stdout" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%-7t] %F:%L - %m%n"/>
        </Console>
        <Console name="stderr" target="SYSTEM_ERR">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%-7t] %F:%L - %m%n" />
            <Filters>
                <ThresholdFilter level="WARN" onMatch="ACCEPT" />
            </Filters>
        </Console>

    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="kafkaAppender"/>

            <!--stdout/stderr included for testing Oozie log4j edits-->
            <AppenderRef ref="stdout"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="stderr"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="org.apache.kafka" level="warn" />
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I want to read kafka connection details from config server as I am developing micro-services using spring boot and spring cloud. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can use system properties in Log4J config: `${sys:some.property}`: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution

I think in the bootstrap context, after reading properties from the config server you can expose the properties for Kafka connection into the system properties and that is going to be available for the downstream logging config: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-commons.adoc#the-bootstrap-application-context